# Android - Curve on Top Left Corner in Image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, page-curl

I have a 4 sharp cornered image to display it my android application. But i want that image to be little curved from Top Left Corner. There should be no animation, nothing. Just an Image with a Curve on its top left corner.

Please look into the following image for reference, for what i wanted to achieved.

[image]

Comment: That can only be achieved with a custom png image set as background.

Comment: Like you mean, Firstly I add a curved image at Background of the ImageView and then place a Foreground Image of my Thumbnail on it ?

Answer (score -1):

take a linear layout with fill parent and set background color while. then use image with in linear layout to show another one image on the screen.

Comment: you have to use image that have curl design.

Comment: :P I think i have mentioned that I have SHARP CORNER IMAGES

Comment: yes you have to make custom image to show as you want , there is no need of coding for that.

Comment: hmmmmm :(, No Other Option ?

Comment: you can do it by animation , but you have mentioned that u don't need.